# Invalid factor level, NA generated while merging a row into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I am including a last row in a dataframe using `rbind` function. My dataframe consists of a month column along with 4 other columns containing some values from different databases.

my data looks like this

```
> dataframe
 Months    Nasa Meteonorm PVplanner   PVGIS
1     Jan  157.41   166.146       101 204.671
2     Feb   167.3   164.346       110 183.123
3     Mar   153.9   169.925       164 173.039
4     Apr  165.97    154.83       185 167.025
5     May  159.86   149.374       215 144.779
6     Jun  144.27   148.937       226 150.542
7     Jul  165.33   163.396       230 166.003
8     Aug  184.07   182.777       219  192.91
9     Sep  176.41   181.575       179 202.416
10    Oct  203.17   163.724       140 209.492
11    Nov  131.26   143.759       106 180.635
```

I want to include a last row (13th row) mentioning the total of all the values.

```
total_Nasa <- sum(dataframe[1:12, 2])
total_Meteonorm <- sum(dataframe[1:12, 3])
total_PVplanner <- sum(dataframe[1:12, 4])
total_PVGIS <- sum(dataframe[1:12, 5])
total <- "Total"

last_row <- c(total, total_Nasa, total_Meteonorm, total_PVplanner, total_PVGIS)


"Total"    "1954.95"  "1943.191" "1965"     "1965"
```

but when I include these using either `rbind` or `dataframe[13, ] <- c(total, total_Nasa, total_Meteonorm, total_PVplanner, total_PVGIS)`

I am getting following warning message. I am not sure how can I add "Total" which is a factor along with these summed values.

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "Total") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

this is how my dataframe looks like after merging the row with the dataframe.

```
> dataframe
   Months    Nasa Meteonorm PVplanner   PVGIS
1     Jan  157.41   166.146       101 204.671
2     Feb   167.3   164.346       110 183.123
3     Mar   153.9   169.925       164 173.039
4     Apr  165.97    154.83       185 167.025
5     May  159.86   149.374       215 144.779
6     Jun  144.27   148.937       226 150.542
7     Jul  165.33   163.396       230 166.003
8     Aug  184.07   182.777       219  192.91
9     Sep  176.41   181.575       179 202.416
10    Oct  203.17   163.724       140 209.492
11    Nov  131.26   143.759       106 180.635
12    Dec     146   154.402        90 174.406
13   <NA> 1954.95  1943.191      1965    1965
```

I want to have "Total" instead of an NA. I am having same issue even after assigning the factors level as

```
dataframe_plot$Months <- factor(dataframe_plot$Months, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Total"))
```

I have also tried this by making a list of values that I want in last row but still getting same warning.

Please guide me how can I solve this.

Regards

Comment: You could just convert `Months` to character first `dataframe$Months <- as.character(dataframe$Months)`

Comment: Wow it was that easy and I am wasting my time from so long. Thanks a lot @Andrew

Comment: I would advise against storing the totals in the last row. That's a very "untidy" (and Excel-ish) way of storing data. Why not store all summary statistics in a separate `vector`? E.g. `library(tidyverse); dataframe %>% summarise(total_Nasa = sum(Nasa), total_Meteonorm = sum(Meteonorm), total_PVplanner = sum(PVplanner), total_PVGIS = sum(PVGIS))`

Comment: @Maurtits this is because I want to plot the dataframe as a table. Otherwise there are many different ways to do this.

Comment: You have another issue which is that the row you are creating is all strings so you are converting everything away from numeric/integer. I'd really suggest keeping the Total separate.  You may want to use row names instead of your strings.